# Android how to update list items with a while loop?

Tags: java, android, list, listview, while-loop

I have a list in witch I have only money amounts (numbers), then I want to create a while loop to pull each item in the list (or amount) to be able to do a calculation like adding the tax to the amount and inserting this new amounts to another list in the same order as the original list.

this is my code:

```
final ArrayList<Double> individuallist = new ArrayList<Double>();
final ArrayAdapter<Double> bb;
bb = new ArrayAdapter<Double>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,individuallist);
listView.setAdapter(bb);
```

//button Next

```
    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnnext);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            counter2 = itotal;
            individuallist.add(0, counter2);
            bb.notifyDataSetChanged();
            item1.setText("0");

        }
    });
```

the itotal comes from a edit text view

so I have another button where I want to create a click event to do the while loop so I can add tax to every amount place the result in another list in the same order and display it in a second list view, so I don't modify the first list items so I can change the tax rate later and be able to modify the second list every time the second button is press and display the second list updated.

Thanks

Comment: Your naming scheme does not match the standard for variables in java. Also understanding this issue would require that you understand how an adapter works.

Comment: Can you point me the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this easily using for loop like this

```
for(int i=0;i<alist.size();i++)
{

  int amount=alist.get(i);
  int taxadded=//caclutaions on amount;
  anotherlist.add(taxadded);
}
```

Comment: this seems to work, but what I'm getting as a result of the new list is the same amount in every item of the list (this amount is the last one in the a list). any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong? Thnaks

Comment: your code works great but I just notice a little issue the list result I get is in opposite order from the first list, so is calculating from the last item in the first list to the first item, is there a way to make it start from the first item in the first list and work it's way to the last item? thanks.